# Hyperledger Explorer error in channel discovery

Tags: hyperledger-explorer

Hyperledger Explorer error in channel discovery:access denied

Channel:ehtchannel received discovery error:access denied-This is the exact error prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.
Solution : Try to run the Hyperledger Explorer once the channel is created and all the peers are joined to the channel

Comment: i have the same issue but i already have a perfectly running network with all the peers joined and a channel created. Any other suggestions?